# Using static IPs with canary deployments in GKE using nginx

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, canary-deployment

I am looking to use a canary deployment in GKE. What I have is the following:

- Ingress controller and ingress deployed in a "prod" namespace. The ingress is assigned a static IP.
- Services deployed in prod and canary namespaces
- Can reach the services ok in the prod namespace.

The issue is when I try to create a configuration for the canary ingress in the canary namespace. What appears to happen is that it does not use the static IP and instead tries to be assigned a new one.

Is it possible to use canary deployments with NGINX in GKE with static IPs?

Comment: As a follow up to this, I've also followed this example closely, creating the canary ingress with a new name in the same namespace, and again, no luck. It tries to assign a new IP to the canary ingress:

https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/k8s-deployment-strategies/tree/master/canary/nginx-ingress

This only happens if I create an ingress with the canary annotations. If I create a new ingress without annotations, it doesn't create a new IP and can use the static one.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a workaround for this in the StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763805/does-gke-support-nginx-ingress-with-static-ip) or by following the steps outlined in the official [Kubernetes Github account](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/static-ip) to use static IP for your canary deployment in GKE. Bear in mind that you need a TLS cert and to make sure your Ingress targets exactly one Ingress controller by specifying the ingress.class annotation, and that you have an ingress controller running in your cluster.